# sim 900 gprs gsm

Tags: command-line

I am communicating through Arduino IDE to sim900 with AT+ commands all was going well then I enter something and now everything that is echoed back to the terminal is in ASCII decimal, how do I return it to display characters instead of numbers.

I have worked through the AT commands but can not find which one I need to change.

Comment: I think the solution will be to enter another something.

Answer (score 0):

To display current configuration of the SIM900 module:

`AT&V`  Display Current Configuration.

And to reset the module to factory setting:

`AT&F`  Factory Defined Configuration.

Check the SIM900 manual:

https://www.espruino.com/datasheets/SIM900_AT.pdf